# Python - I want to convert words to 8 bit binary, but certain characters are in 7 bits

Tags: python, pyscript

I have a code (python) that converts any character on a keyboard to binary, but if the character has 2 zeros in the beginning of the binary code, it deletes 1 of the zeros, so it can't be converted back.

```
<body>
  <p>Click to open <a href="localhost:8000" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">local host</a>.</p>
  <div>Type here to convert characters to binary;</div>
  <input type="text" id="test-input"/>
  <button id="submit-button" type="submit" pys-onClick="my_function">OK</button>
  <p>Text: <div id="test-output"></div></p>
  <p>Binary: <div id="test-output2"></div></p>

    <py-script>
        from js import console

        def my_function(*args, **kwargs):

            #print('args:', args)
            #print('kwargs:', kwargs)

            console.log(f'args: {args}')
            console.log(f'kwargs: {kwargs}')
    
            text = Element('test-input').element.value

            #print('text:', text)
            console.log(f'text: {text}')
            textTwo = text.replace(" ", "_").replace("@", "_").replace("#", "_").replace("$", "_").replace("%", "_").replace("^", "_").replace("&", "_").replace("*", "_").replace("(", "_").replace(")", "_").replace("-", "_").replace("+", "_").replace("=", "_").replace("{", "_").replace("}", "_").replace("[", "_").replace("]", "_").replace("|", "_").replace(":", "_").replace(";", "_").replace('"', "_").replace("<", "_").replace("/", "_").replace("!", "_").replace("'", "_").replace("?", "_").replace(",", "_").replace(".", "_").replace(">", "_")

            output = ' '.join(map(bin,bytearray(textTwo,'ascii')))
            new_output = output.replace("b", "")
            Element('test-output').element.innerText = textTwo
            Element('test-output2').element.innerText = new_output
    </py-script>
  <br>
  <div>Type here to convert binary to characters;</div>
  <input type="text" id="test-inputs"/>
  <button id="submit-button22" type="submit" pys-onClick="my_functions">OK</button>
  <p>Binary: <div id="test-outputs"></div></p>
  <p>Text: <div id="test-outputs2"></div></p>
    <py-script>
        from js import console
        import re

        def my_functions(*args, **kwargs):

            #print('args:', args)
            #print('kwargs:', kwargs)

            console.log(f'args: {args}')
            console.log(f'kwargs: {kwargs}')
    
            text = Element('test-inputs').element.value

            #print('text:', text)
            console.log(f'text: {text}')
            newName = re.sub('[\\\\qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmQWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM23456789]', '', text)
            new_text = newName.replace(" ", "")
            bins = new_text
            binc = [bins[i:i + 8] for i in range(0, len(bins), 8)]
            nums = [int(chunk, 2) for chunk in binc]
            output = ''.join(chr(num) for num in nums)
            Element('test-outputs').element.innerText = text
            Element('test-outputs2').element.innerText = output
    </py-script>
</body>
```

Everything converts nicely, but numbers don't. I fixed it so all marks like !@#$%^&*() and spaces are put as _.

Edit: Here is the part that needs fixing;

```
from js import console

def my_function(*args, **kwargs):

    #print('args:', args)
    #print('kwargs:', kwargs)

    console.log(f'args: {args}')
    console.log(f'kwargs: {kwargs}')
    
    text = Element('test-input').element.value

    #print('text:', text)
    console.log(f'text: {text}')
    textTwo = text.replace(" ", "_").replace("@", "_").replace("#", "_").replace("$", "_").replace("%", "_").replace("^", "_").replace("&", "_").replace("*", "_").replace("(", "_").replace(")", "_").replace("-", "_").replace("+", "_").replace("=", "_").replace("{", "_").replace("}", "_").replace("[", "_").replace("]", "_").replace("|", "_").replace(":", "_").replace(";", "_").replace('"', "_").replace("<", "_").replace("/", "_").replace("!", "_").replace("'", "_").replace("?", "_").replace(",", "_").replace(".", "_").replace(">", "_")

    output = ' '.join(map(bin,bytearray(textTwo,'ascii')))
    new_output = output.replace("b", "")
    Element('test-output').element.innerText = textTwo
    Element('test-output2').element.innerText = new_output
```

Comment: Could you include *just* the code without a surrounding HTML document?

Comment: Could you add examples of sample input, the expected output, and the output you're getting instead?

Comment: Please make a [mcve] with just the Python functions taking text without the HTML with sample inputs and expected vs. actual outputs.

Comment: Use a single call to `re.sub()` instead of dozens of `.replace()` calls to remove all the punctuation.

Comment: The input is: kyle 3. The sample output is: 01101011 01111001 01101100 01100101 01011111 0110011. The expected output for the number 3 is: 00110011. When there are 2 zeros at the beginning of a binary (like the 3) it prints without the 2nd zero (0110011 instead of 00110011).

Comment: Re: "Could you include just the code without a surrounding HTML document?"
@mkrieger1 "just the code" in this case would make it make _no sense_ for 95% + Python developers - this is a script-Python program meant to be run embedded in HTML, and the "surrounding HTML" contains essential code so that the pieces pasted a fully functional minimal example.

Comment: @jsbueno I don't think all that is needed to demonstrate an issue with formatting integers as binary numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`output = ' '.join(map(bin,bytearray(textTwo,'ascii')))` doesn't make sure the binary is 8 digits long, use:

```
output = ' '.join([format(n,'08b') for n in textTwo.encode('ascii')])
```

(and you won't need `new_output` line).

Comment: Yes, that worked. It is a school project, and that line that you changed was the line the teacher wanted me to use, but it doesn't work as shown. Thank you for fixing that.